# display the content of ftp folder in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ftp, web-parts, ftpwebrequest

I want to display the content of ftp folder in the sharepoint 
If possible I want to upload files to there and download files from there 
I want to use SharePoint only as presentation layer 
im using sharepoint 2010

Is it possible ? 
And how ?

thanks !

Comment: I don't think sharepoint 2010 has any such OOB feature. You will have to do go with custom developed by developing a webpart which does this. There are many 3rd party .NET components which allow you to easy carry out FTP operations programatically. You may need to buy one of those components to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable FileStream support on your SQL Server.
See [manual](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2011/02/22/filestream-and-sharepoint-2010.aspx) for more info.

Comment: didnt understand how this is helping me . =\

Comment: You will be able to save documents to file system.